# mongoose deleting and updating in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I need to take array from my model, delete from it some days and push to it some other days. It looks something like `deleteAndUpdate`.

To sum up:
I need to take `Car` from database. Take `reserved` property (it's a array), then delete from `reserved` days from given list, and then add to `reserved` days from other given list.

My model look:

```
const CarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    mark:{
        type: String,
        required: true,},
    model:{
        type: String,
        required: true,},
    price:{
        type: Number,
        required: true,},
    available: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,},
    reserved:{
        type:[Date],

    },
    pic_1:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    pic_2:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },


},
{ collection: 'cars' }
)
```

I take car by: `var car= await Car.findById(carID);` and then i need to do sth like that:

```
car['reserved'].deleted(old_days);
car['reserved'].push(new_days;
car.save();
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update can't allow multiple operation at a time in same field, It will throw multiple write error and would create a conflict at your field,

#### Regular update:

If you want to do it by regular update query you have to do separate do 2 queries,

- **Delete days:** If you want to delete multiple days use `$pullAll`, and for single you can use `$pull`

```
var old_days = [new Date("2021-04-24"), new Date("2021-04-25")];
await Car.updateOne({ _id: carID }, { $pullAll: { reserved: old_days } });
```

- **Add days:** if you want to add multiple days you can use `$push` with `$each`, and for single you can use just `$push`,

```
var new_days = [new Date("2021-04-26"), new Date("2021-04-27")];
await Car.updateOne({ _id: carID }, { $push: { reserved: { $each: new_days } } });
```

#### Update with aggregation pipeline:

If you are looking for single query you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of reserved array and remove old days
- `$concatArrays` to concat reserved array with new days

```
var old_days = [new Date("2021-04-24"), new Date("2021-04-25")];
var new_days = [new Date("2021-04-26"), new Date("2021-04-27")];
await Car.updateOne(
  { _id: carID },
  [{
    $set: {
      reserved: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$reserved",
          cond: { $not: { $in: ["$$this", old_days] } }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      reserved: {
        $concatArrays: ["$reserved", new_days]
      }
    }
  }]
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oTT6VQAtFDc)

Answer (score 1):

To remove old item from array you can use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

```
car.update(
  { _id: carID },
  { $pull: { 'reserved': old_days } }
);
```

You can use **$unset** to unset the value in the array (set it to null), but not to remove it completely.

To add the item new_days in array, You can either use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)  or [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

```
car.update(
  { _id: carID },
  { $push: { 'reserved': new_days } }
);
```